# How to solve the problem of finding item by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

When I follow the route: '/gallery' I get all the items from the file './posts.json' and display them on screen. But when I turn the route: '/gallery/:id' I want to receive one item by its `id`.

But I get an error: `const pictureId = this.formatePicture.findIndex(p => p.id == parseInt(id)); TypeError: this.formatePicture.findIndex is not a function.` I tried to do `for in` by `data`, but after the cycle there are no object properties.

**Tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this problem so that I get the item by `id` when I go to the route '/gallery/:id'**

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const Database = require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.id) {
        const picture = db.read(req.query.id);
        picture.then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
    } else {
        const pictures = db.read();
        pictures.then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
    }
});

app.get('/gallery/:id', (req, res) => {
    const picture = db.read(req.params.id);
    if (!picture) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send();
    } else {
        picture.then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

**db.js:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
class Database {
constructor() {
     this.formatePicture = [];
}
    read (id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile('./posts.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }else if(id) {
                    this.formatePicture = JSON.parse(data);
                    const pictureId = this.formatePicture.findIndex(p => p.id == parseInt(id));
                    resolve(pictureId)
                }
                else {
                    resolve(data)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

**posts.json:**

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
      "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/39/16/903916b9f0db6992f1a4b66ae3129fbe.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
      "url": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/okup/images/d/da/C683c20a5b0ae062b2325653f2fd3bdf.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170131193210&path-prefix=da"
    }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data parsed is an object, the array you need to target is in the field `posts`

`this.formatePicture.posts.findIndex(...)`

Another way to achieve this without modifying your db code, would be to change the structure in `posts.json` so that it looks like this

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
      "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/39/16/903916b9f0db6992f1a4b66ae3129fbe.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
      "url": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/okup/images/d/da/C683c20a5b0ae062b2325653f2fd3bdf.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170131193210&path-prefix=da"
    }
]
```

---

#### As a side note:

You might want to use `find` instead of `findIndex` because `pictureId`is an index with the initial code you shared

It could look like that

```
const picture = this.formatePicture.find(p => p.id == parseInt(id));

// checking if we found an entry first
if (picture) {
    resolve(picture.id);
} else {
    reject(/* some error about resource not being found */)
}
```

Comment: i had  error after edit code: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 0

Comment: You might need to set `res.status(200)` before sending `data` in case of success

Comment: when  i add  res.status(200) before  res.send(data); i had error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 0

Comment: if i changed  es.status(200) to (statusCode >= 100 && statusCode < 600 ? err.code : 500); i had this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: statusCode is not defined

Comment: I used "res.status(200).json(data);" and code worked